# How can I test heteroskedasticity in a Tobit model with Stata 12?

Tags: statistical-significance, stata, heteroscedasticity, r-squared, tobit-regression

1. I want to test heteroskedasticity in a Tobit model with Stata 12. But I don't know how to do that.
2. When I used an OLS model, I tested heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation, and didn't find much, but the OLS model isn't significant (Prob > *F* = 0.54) and *R*² is small = 0.01. How can I improve that problem? Thanks.

Comment: 1) looks like a request for code. 2) implies that your regression is a very poor fit. What kind of advice do you think we can give? You need a better model or data more suitable for your research objectives. Alternatively, tell us much more and you may get better advice. For example, what model are you fitting with what data? What correlation matrix do you get for your variables, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm examining the impact of cash-flow uncertainty on dividends according to Chay and Suh research (2009). First, I use OLS model to examine the correlation of variables and after that I use tobit model to test the impact of key factors on dividend and logit model to examnine the probability of paying dividends. But almost my results of models is so poor fit.

Comment: The correlation matrix for my variables:               DV/E SRVOL RE/TE OWN MBR
DV/E 1.0000    
SRVOL -0.1937 1.0000   
RE/TE -0.0637 0.1455 1.0000  
OWN 0.02300 0.1316 0.0152 1.0000 
MBR -0.0067 0.2159 0.2455 0.4959 1.0000

Comment: You can edit your question making that easier to read. Which variable are you trying to predict? DV/E? A name and date reference means almost nothing to people outside your field. There is a general pattern of very weak correlations there. The exception is the correlation of about 0.50.

Comment: I would take a peek at two part models given your question. The Stata implementation is called `tpm`.

Answer (score 1):

Section 16.4.6 of Cameron and Trivedi's [MUS book](http://cameron.econ.ucdavis.edu/musbook/mus.html) has Stata code and intuition for an auxiliary regression test for homoskedasticity when the outcome is logged and the zeros are dealt with in ad hoc way. The alternative hypothesis is that $\sigma^2_i=\exp (x_i' \alpha  )$. It's a bit involved, so I will not reproduce it here. You can find a reasonably annotated do-file for chapter 16 [on their book site](http://www.stata-press.com/data/musr.html). In fact, that whole chapter is one of the clearest explanations of all the various approaches to censored data.

There are two other alternatives:

1. Testing the corresponding probit model (rather than the OLS) for heteroskedasticity using the `hetprob` can also tell you something about heteroskedasticity in the Tobit arena.
2. There's also a user-written `tobithetm` command that you can get from SSC. It deals with multiplicative hetroskedasticity and produces coefficients that can be used to test a formal hypothesis.

Comment: Dimitriy V. Masterov, all of two other alternatives to test heteroskedasticity in a Tobit model with Stata 12, I can't find a free code. Would you please help me to find a free code. Thank you so much

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by free. Stata's user-written commands are free to all (just install with `ssc install tobithet`). `hetprobit` is part of official Stata 13, but was called `hetprob` in Stata 12, so it should be available to you. You can see that from `help whatsnew12to13`.